how to simplify this code using lambda and filters
   final List<String> resources = someSao.getResource()
            .stream()
            .filter(Resource::isPresentInDB)
            .map(Resource::getType)
            .toList();

    final String str = resources.contains("A") ?  "A" :  resources.get(0);

I know there should be a way to simplify the last line. I am trying to basically prioritize returning A if it is present in the filtered resources list, and if A is not present just return the first thing it finds. (findFirst).
Can someone please help me combining the two different statements in one.

possibly have a priority associated with your type and then findfirst after sorting.. otherwise what you have is simplified enough.

You can use str = someSao.getResource().stream() .anyMatch(r -> r.isPresentInDB() && r.getType().equals("A"))? "A": someSao.getResource() .stream() .filter(Resource::isPresentInDB) .map(Resource::getType) .findFirst().orElseThrow(); but this will only pay off if you have a rather large likelihood of having an "A" or a large number of elements and avoiding the creation of the list matters. Regarding simplicity, the code in the question is preferrable. Or use a loop…

You could do something like this:
final String str = someSao.getResource()
            .stream()
            .filter(Resource::isPresentInDB)
            .findFirst()
            .map(r -> r.getType().contains("A")? "A": r.getType())
            .orElse("A");


You can try below solution, which has all the necessary null handlings and in case no matching element with type as "A", simply returning first element from list:
    List<Resource> resourceList = someSao.getResource();

final Resource matchingResource = Optional.ofNullable(resourceList).orElse(Collections.emptyList()).stream()
        .filter(Resource::isPresentInDB)
        .filter(resource -> null != resource && "A".equalsIgnoreCase(resource.getType())).findFirst()
        .orElse(resourceList.get(0));

